# How to concatenate Listbox selections into a single cell

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have this code to bring the data from my Userform to my Cells:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("hoja2").Select 'selecciona la hoja "datos"
Range("B8").Select 'selecciona el rango (en este caso la celda) "A1"
Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell) 'encuentra la ultima celda con datos
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'en la ultima celda con datos, muevete una fila abajo
Loop 'bucle
ActiveCell = ListBox1
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell = ListBox2
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell = ListBox3
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell = TextBox1
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell = TextBox2 'copia el contenido del textbox2 a la celda activa
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell = TextBox3
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell = ListBox4
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell = ListBox5
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell = ListBox6
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell = ImpGlob
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell = TextBox4
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell = TextBox5
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveCell = TextBox6
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
TextBox1 = Empty 'textbox1, dejar en blanco
TextBox2 = Empty 'etc
TextBox3 = Empty
TextBox4 = Empty
TextBox5 = Empty
TextBox6 = Empty
ListBox1 = Empty 'textbox1, dejar en blanco
ListBox2 = Empty 'etc
ListBox3 = Empty
ListBox4 = Empty
ListBox5 = Empty
ListBox6 = Empty
MsgBox "Datos guardados" 'mostrar el mensaje "Datos guardados"
End Sub
```

The problem is that when i choose multiple items for some listboxes where i need a multiple choice, the cell stays blanks.

Is there any way to put the items in a list like "item 1, item 2, items 3" in a single cell?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what You wanted, I made something very similar yesterday; Take all the information from multiple textboxes/listboxes and put it in a new row at the bottom of a "table". Here's one using your names:

```
Public Sub NuevoDatos()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim Dtab As Object
Dim Tbox As OLEObject
Dim R As Long, C As Long, i As Long
Dim Ans As Variant
Set wks = Sheets("hoja2")
Set Dtab = Sheets("hoja2").ListObjects("Table1")
Dim N As Long
N = Dtab.HeaderRowRange.Row + ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).ListRows.Count
Ans = MsgBox("Crear una nueva entrada?", vbYesNo, "Entrada de datos")
    If Ans = vbNo Then
        ActiveSheet.TextBox1.Activate
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Ans = vbYes Then
    Dtab.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
    R = Dtab.ListRows.Count
    C = Dtab.ListColumns.Count
    Dtab.ListRows(R).Range.Cells(1).Value = Now()
    For i = 1 To 3
        Dtab.ListRows(R).Range.Cells(i + 1).Value = wks.OLEObjects("ListBox" & i).Object.List(ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox" & i).Object.ListIndex)
        wks.OLEObjects("ListBox" & i).Object.ListIndex = -1
    Next i
    For i = 4 To 6
        Dtab.ListRows(R).Range.Cells(i + 1).Value = wks.OLEObjects("TextBox" & (i - 3)).Object.Value
        wks.OLEObjects("TextBox" & (i - 3)).Object.Value = ""
    Next i
    For i = 7 To 9
        Dtab.ListRows(R).Range.Cells(i + 1).Value = wks.OLEObjects("ListBox" & (i - 3)).Object.List(ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ListBox" & (i - 3)).Object.ListIndex)
        wks.OLEObjects("ListBox" & (i - 3)).Object.ListIndex = -1
    Next i
    For i = 10 To 12
        Dtab.ListRows(R).Range.Cells(i + 1).Value = wks.OLEObjects("TextBox" & (i - 6)).Object.Value
        wks.OLEObjects("TextBox" & (i - 6)).Object.Value = ""
    Next i
MsgBox "¡Entrada de datos completa! xD "
End If
End Sub
```

So, I tried to make it work like you wanted ;) enjoy~!
note: This sub is for activeX listbox/textbox on this... the syntax changes depending on what *type* you use

Comment: I added today's date to the first cell... you can delete that if you don't want it! :D Just remove the `Dtab.ListRows(R).Range.Cells(1).Value = Now()` and remove the `+1` from the `Dtab.ListRows(R).Range.Cells(i + 1).Value`

Answer (score 0):

Use `vbCrLf` (Carriage Return/Line Feed) like this:

```
ActiveCell.Value = "item 1" & vbCrLf & "item 2" & vbCrLf & "item 3"
```

**Updated**

Your question was not very clear then. Try this:

```
Private Sub Test()
  Dim nIndex As Integer

  Range("A1").Value = ""
  For nIndex = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(nIndex) Then
      Range("A1").Value = ListBox1.List(nIndex, 0) & vbCrLf & Range("A1").Value
    End If
  Next
  Range("A1").Value = Left$(Range("A1").Value, Len(Range("A1").Value) - 1)
End Sub
```

Modify it to suit your needs. Obviously you will have to change the name of the listbox to match yours, and trigger the routine somehow, and change the Range to suit your needs.

Comment: but i still need to take the selected item from the listbox. wich i cant

Comment: Updated for you.